# Random NTFS read/write failure

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

I'm having a really strange problem. Recently I upgraded my machine with a new hard drive - 1TB Western Digital WD Caviar Black, 64MB cache, SATAIII-600.

I have installed a new Windows and I've got 4 partitions:

- 2 NTFS
- 1 ext4
- 1 Linux swap.

The problem comes with the second NTFS partition which is used as a bridge between the OSes. I store personal projects, music, movies and so on. Unfortunately Windows 7 is having a problem with the partition and if I try to copy a directory (with about 10,000 files of PHP sources) it stops copying it at a random place.

There are no errors, no nothing. It just stops copying at a random file. I've got no clue what  is wrong with it but it's definitely a Windows problem. I tried to copy/paste the same directory into the same partition and from Slackware, GParted (Live USB), Ubuntu (Live USB) and it worked like a charm.

I've tried doing `chknfs` over the partition but that didn't fix anything.

Are there any suggestions? I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now without any luck.

Comment: Do any of the files have extremely long full pathnames or do any of the names contain unusual characters?  How are you trying to do the copy?

Comment: No, no long names or paths. The copy/paste is with Explorer, also tried via Cygwin but had the absolute same result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this problem by doing `chkdsk /F Partition:` and `chknfs /C Partition:`. Although I did this a couple of times the previous days as well, this time it worked. I've got no idea what the heck was wrong with it but I guess ntfs sucks big time.